# Error on Docker on Windows 10 Home and WSL

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running WSL, specifically WLinux Distribution. I have installed Docker for both Windows and Wlinux as well as the Docker Brigde for WSL.

Now I try to start my Docker instance, `Docker-Toolbox`, but I get this error:

```
➜ docker-machine.exe start
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a dhcp server. Sometimes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
Error setting up host only network on machine start: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe modifyvm default --nic2 hostonly --nictype2 82540EM --nicpromisc2 deny --hostonlyadapter2 VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2 --cableconnected2 on failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_FAIL (0x80004005) - Unspecified error (extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Write)" at line 525 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

I have tried various solutions, but nothing seems to make my docker run. Even If I run it from docker's own terminal it still times out and gives an error for not responding.

Does anyone know what is wrong and how to fix it? As you can see Docker recognizes that default docker installation is present and tries to start it, but something is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/jwilson8767/00a46f5ca63327d5bfd802f87b702c8d

You don't need the first part, since you already have docker installed in the linux subsystem. Start at line 13. You just need to run these commands once.

Also, see my comment (https://gist.github.com/jwilson8767/00a46f5ca63327d5bfd802f87b702c8d#gistcomment-2587348) for two modifications you have to make due to changes in docker-toolbox.